# Limit $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(x^2-x)}{x^2-\tan x}$ without l'Hospital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(x^2-x)}{x^2-\tan x}$$

I could not solve this without l'hospital.

Comment: why does de l'hopital fail?

Comment: @Exodd I'm guessing he means he wants to be able to solve this w/o L'Hopital

Comment: We haven't seen that law yet..

Comment: Friendly reminder, there is no S in L'hopital's name.

Comment: @AYARcom What are you allowed to use?

Comment: You're right JMoravitz.

Comment: We are allowder to use only trigonometry rules

Comment: @JMoravitz: it is common enough to include an "s" instead of the circumflex "ô" in L'Hospital's theorem. Some introductory calculus books do this, for example the one by Stewart. The French word "hôpital" is "hospital" in English.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin\left(x^{2}-x\right)}{x^{2}-\tan x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin\left(x^{2}-x\right)}{x^{2}-x}\frac{x^{2}-x}{x^{2}-\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin\left(x^{2}-x\right)}{x^{2}-x}\cos x\frac{x-1}{x\cos x-\frac{\sin x}{x}}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Use the taylor series of the numerator and the denominator.